# Rails polymorphic association error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, polymorphism

I'm having problems with a polymorphic association.

A quick explanation about my project.  You can see it here: majorfinder.com  On my app there will be majors, schools, and careers.  I want to be able to add reviews for each.  Since I'm just starting out I'm just beginning with adding reviews for majors but creating the association so that when I get to the careers and schools the reviews association will go quickly.

Here are my associations:

models/review.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :reviewable, polymorophic: true
```

models/user.rb

```
has_many :reviews
```

models/major.rb

```
has_many :reviews, as: :reviewable
```

My db schema for reviews looks like this:

```
create_table "reviews", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "review"
    t.datetime "created_at",      :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      :null => false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "reviewable_id"
    t.string   "reviewable_type"
  end
```

In my majors controller I've followed [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised) in order to create a url that looks like this www.majorfinder.com/majors/major-name.  So part of my majors controller looks like this:

```
def show
    @major = Major.find_by_slug(params[:id]).includes(:reviews => :user)
end
```

In my majors show page I have:

```
<% @reviews.each do |review| %>
    <div>
      <h3><%= link_to review.review,
        :controller => "reviews", :action => "show", :id => review.id %></h3>
      <small>Posted on <%= review.created_at %> by
        <a href="#"><%= review.user.profile_name %></a></small>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

And lastly, here are my routes:

```
resources :majors, has_many: :reviews
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in MajorsController#show

undefined method `includes' for #<Major:0x007f9466e001a8>
```

Here it is from the console:

```
Started GET "/majors/statistics" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-05 07:45:01 -0700
Processing by MajorsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"has_many"=>:reviews, "id"=>"statistics"}
  Major Load (24.2ms)  SELECT "majors".* FROM "majors" WHERE "majors"."slug" = 'statistics' LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "majors".* FROM "majors" WHERE "majors"."slug" = 'statistics' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `includes' for #<Major:0x007f8ad51fdd00>):
  app/controllers/majors_controller.rb:16:in `show'
```

Line 16 in the majors_controller.rb file is this one:

```
@major = Major.find_by_slug(params[:id]).includes(:reviews => :user)
```

Can you see what I'm missing or what I should change?  It seems like the solution is simple but I am not sure what it is. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your problem is pretty clear: the `includes` method isn't defined for Major instances. I'm not quite sure what the fix to your problem is. Did you get that from an example? What are you trying to do with that method invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is eager load `:reviews` when you find the Major. You are close but your order is backwards. It needs to be

```
@major = Major.includes(:reviews => :user).find_by_slug(params[:id])
```

For more information on eager loading checkout this [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) article.

Comment: Yes, exactly!  Thank you!  Thanks for the rails guide too.  I have been looking for that but didn't know the term eager loading.  I really appreciate it!